# bootstrap 3 how to close modal from external content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to close the modal window from the contents of my external link.

```
<a id="loginLink" data-toggle="modal" href="/Home/Login" data-target="#modalLogin">Log in</a>

<div class="modal" id="modalLogin" align="center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to put the button

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
```

in there because the external content logic in there where it is supposed to close the window based on some actions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to close the modal programmatically, e.g.

```
$('#modalLogin').modal('hide');
```

That way if you have something else on the page (for instance an `$.async()` call with a `.done()` function, you can execute the above to close the modal.

This will only hide the modal, not remove it from the DOM, if you want to perform certain actions when a modal is being hidden you can bind a function to the bootstrap events that are triggered and associated with the modal, e.g.

```
$('#modalLogin').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage for more details.